# Espresso Perform Exception happening in CI only

Tags: continuous-integration, android-espresso, bitrise

I am using Bitrise to run some Android espresso UI tests, but I cant seem to find a solution for this Perform Exception:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'with id: com.selfcarecatalyst.healthstorylines.adda:id/male'.
    at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
```

Im testing a sign up page that has a few fields. If i skip clicking one field, I get the same error on the next click on this form. The relevant code is:

```
public void clickMale_onInfoPage(){

    onView(withId(R.id.male)).perform(click());
}
public void setFirstName_onInfoPage(String name){
    onView(withId(R.id.first_name)).perform(typeText(name));
    closeSoftKeyboard();
}
```

setName is called first, and i added a softclosekeyboard thinking this would solve it but it did not :(

This is running through a CI, and sorry but Im a little new and not sure how to get a better error message/stacktrace. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am still not able to get it into work but I'll publish a how to as soon I get it into work. The first thing you need to do is to make sure your test is working on your laptop. Then on Bitrise add `create android emulator` and `start android emulator` from stack. after that you must add script in order to move apk-s to emulator and run Espresso. you can follow my progress at http://stackoverflow.com/q/36753486/513413

Comment: sure il check it out thanks! my test works locally, the issues only happen on CI and it is hard to debug

Answer (score 0):

You should also try to call `closeSoftKeyboard()` **before** performing the click action.

Comment: Right before the perform click call?

    `public void clickMale_onInfoPage(){
        closeSoftKeyboard();
        onView(withId(R.id.male)).perform(click());
    }`