# Android reports "Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo {}"

Tags: android, automation, android-espresso, bitrise

There are a lot of topics/questions regard this issue on stackoverflow (such as [Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{ }](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21294945/513413)) and other website but the thing that make my problem different than others is I am working on automation. So let me give you more details.

I have no problem when I'm testing on local machine (I mean my laptop). I can run Espresso testing and all tests passes.

Now, I want to run these tests on CI (Bitrise in my case). I create and run Emulator. I confirm there is no issue there. I have following script:

```
...
# Check which instrumentation packages have been installed on your device, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23394559/513413
echo ""
echo "Check which instrumentation packages have been installed..."
adb shell pm list instrumentation

# Running tests
echo ""
echo "running test..."
adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class my.package.name.MyActivityTest my.package.name.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

This is my output from CI:

```
Check which instrumentation packages have been installed...
instrumentation:com.android.emulator.smoketests/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner (target=com.android.emulator.smoketests)
instrumentation:com.android.smoketest.tests/com.android.smoketest.SmokeTestRunner (target=com.android.smoketest)
instrumentation:com.example.android.apis/.app.LocalSampleInstrumentation (target=com.example.android.apis)
running test...
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{my.package.name.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: my.package.name.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:1093)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:371)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:100)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:251)
```

I have following line of code in `defaultConfig` of `app.gradle` file:

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
```

I have `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` under my EditConfiguration as you see in the following link.

[image]

I guess my test fails because I don't have this command in my CI's emulator. So my question is how I can add it via command line? Is that possible?

## Update

This is my full script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# List of devices attached
adb devices

# List all *.apk files inside /bitrise/deploy path
echo "List of all *.apk files in $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR"
cd $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR && ls

# Push and Install main apk file
echo ""
echo "Pushing main apk at $BITRISE_APK_PATH to /data/local/tmp/my.package.name and install it..."
adb push $BITRISE_APK_PATH /data/local/tmp/my.package.name
adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/my.package.name"

# Push and Install Test Unaligned apk file
echo ""
echo "Pushing test unaligned apk at $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR/my-app-debug-unaligned.apk to /data/local/tmp/my.package.name.test and install it..."
adb push $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR/my-app-debug-unaligned.apk /data/local/tmp/my.package.name.test
adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/my.package.name.test"

# Check which instrumentation packages have been installed on your device, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23394559/513413
echo ""
echo "Check which instrumentation packages have been installed..."
adb shell pm list instrumentation

# Running tests
echo ""
echo "switch directory to $BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR"
cd $BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR
echo "running test..."
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class my.package.name.path.MinHappyPathTest my.package.name.path/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Comment: hey @Hesam did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You must install (adb install) and application APK and test APK (this is different APK) before running "adb shell am instrument".

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question with full script. I've moved those two apk files.